# String interpolation inside onclick (Ionic 2 + Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, syntax-error, ionic3

Simple question, I am trying to pass a string inside an "onclick" in my Ionic 2 app but it keeps giving me an error.

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp(null, null, '{{sound.file}}', null)">Enviar no whats</button>
```

**error log**

```
 Can't bind to 'onclick' since it isn't a known native property
```

Comment: try `(click)=".."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<button (click)="share(sound.file)">Enviar no whats</button>
```

And in your component

```
public share(file: string): void {
    window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp(null, null, file, null);
}
```

You should avoid including *logic* in the view, putting it in the component code instead.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)